# Actor's action isn't dynamic at runtime?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a group of Actor that changing position depending on each other. But do the action get the latest position of Actor?

Below is the partial code I have use for Actor

```
for(int i=0 ; i<symbolFrames.length; i++){

    nextSymbolIndex=nextSymbol(i);//get the index of next symbol
    moveByOneFrame=Actions.moveBy(0,stopFrames[0].getRectangle().height,spinSpeed);


    resetFrame=Actions.moveTo(
            stopFrames[0].getRectangle().x,
            symbolFrames[nextSymbol(i)].getRectangle().y-symbolFrames[nextSymbol(i)].getRectangle().height
    );//here is the action that will get the position of another Actor.

    chain=new SequenceAction(
                Actions.repeat((symbolFrames.length-i),moveByOneFrame),//move by frame depend on its position
                Actions.forever(
                        Actions.sequence(
                                Actions.repeat(1,resetFrame)
                                ,Actions.repeat((symbolFrames.length),moveByOneFrame))//moveByOneFrame
                        )//repeat the movement unless stop is called
                );

    symbolFrames[i].addAction(chain);

}//this whole code is running outside of render loop
```

Is the action able to get the runtime value of other actors? If no , is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: What does the getRectangle method return. Why not use the getX() and getY() from the actor class?

Comment: i flipped the stage , and resized the game , the value return is not right , the rectangle method do convert the coordinate using localToStage method

Comment: It looks like you set the position once maybe create a custom Action that takes an Actor reference and updates accordingly. Im not really sure could you add the getRectangle code.

Comment: the main question is the action is .forever , and the position of the actor is changing at runtime. I need a action that get the other actor position at runtime